# Maximize sum of vectors

Tags: c#, linear-programming

Given a number of vectors, and an unknown variable for each vector, say for example:

v1, v2, v3...vn and x1, x2, x3...xn

and a target vector vt

I am trying to create an algorithm to maximize p by setting x1, x2, x3, xn
such that:

```
v1*x1 + v2*x2 + v3*x3 + vn*xn = vt*p
```

the coefficients, x1, x2, x3, and xn, are constrained like:

```
0 <= x1 <= c1
0 <= x2 <= c2
0 <= x3 <= c3
0 <= xn <= cn
```

where, c1, c2, c3, and cn are given constants.

How would I go about writing an algorithm to find the variables such that p is maximized?

Edit: the vectors in this example have a length of 6, and there can be as many as n number of the vectors. So Gaussian elimination as I understand it would not work when n is greater then 6.

Edit2: I discovered a  way of looking at the problem, but still stuck as to what kind of algorithm to use to solve it. Here is a vector drawing I did to explain in different way what I am trying to do:
[image]

This depiction is two dimensional, I imagine that the shape would become more complex in higher dimensions and with more vectors.

Comment: What about some heuristic? Genetic algorithm or tabu search?

Comment: This feels very similar to `k-means`. Doesn't end up optimal, though (neither does genetic algortihm).

Comment: I came up with something but I'm not sure if I understand the input right. This either doesn't work since `p` isn't a vector or all vectors have to have a dependency between them and thus can be removed altogether, is that right? Since `v1 * x1 + v2 * x2 = vt * p` would never work for e.g. `v1` = {0, 0}, `v2` = {0, 1}, `vt` = {1, 1}.

Comment: I too think the answer should be simple(ish): just find one solution (p=1) (for example with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination) and then it's a matter of a scalar-factor to get the x's into range and maximize them

Comment: I am not sure a heuristic would work, since there are no step values that are either maximum or not maximum (correct me if I am wrong). Edited main post to contain more information specific to my case.

Comment: K-means looks interesting. So would that sort of, reduce the variables until the equation can be solved by Gaussian elimination by "grouping" the unknowns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution:

On the math exchange I asked how to format the problem as a linear program:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1200260/how-to-maximize-the-sum-of-vectors-in-target-direction

With the problem in linear program format, its just a matter of finding an lp solver library, here is the one I plan on using:
http://www.coin-or.org/projects/

It is in c++ , and its possible to use a wrapper so that its functions can be called in c#.